# Sending emails from Web API without exposing service IP/URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, security, azure

I am developing an application that provides account management features. Implementation wise, it has one MVC App for UI and ***separate*** couple of Web API services for business logic.

I need to manage sending mails to users in couple of situations like following

- user creates an account & Web API sends confirmation/activation mail
- user forgot password & Web API sends reset link

Now the question is, how to send mails to users without exposing Web API host IP (or URL)? Probably, I can do following:

1. Create an action in MVC which when called, sends the info to the
   appropriate Web API controller method
2. With appropriate parameters, include above action as the href in the mail sent by Web API

Another approach could be, simply sending the code to user without links and asking user to enter that token on the UI (user knows the MVC UI link).

I would prefer the second approach. Is this the right approach? Is there any other better way?

Things to note:

- Web API will use SendGrid to send mail
- The system (MVC & Web API) will be hosted in Azure (I mention this to
  know any pitfalls in the above first approach when Azure scales out the
  system).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the confusion. You would never link the user directly to the Web Api, anyways. Essentially, the MVC project just becomes the UI around the Web Api in this scenario, so for example:

1. User loads "Signup" page on MVC site and submits the form there to an action on the MVC site
2. The MVC site's post action calls the Web Api to register the user and send the confirmation email. Then, redirects the user to another page on the MVC site.
3. The Web Api sends the confirmation email to the user with a link to confirm *on the MVC site*.
4. User clicks the link in the email, and is taken to the confirmation page on the MVC site.
5. The MVC site, again, interacts with the Web Api to confirm the user, and redirects the user to another page on the MVC site.

As you can see, at no point in the above is the user even aware that a Web Api component exists. The only interaction they have is with the MVC site.

Now, I would go a step even further and say the MVC site shouldn't know it's working with a Web Api, *either*. Essentially, it's just using the Web Api as it would a database. It just knows it needs to perform some function that just happens to be being completed by a Web Api. As result, you should wrap up the Web Api calls into a service class, implementing an interface. For example:

```
public interface IService

public class WebApiService : IService
```

On `IService`, you would define all the actions a client of the service could take. `RegisterUser`, `SendConfirmationEmail`, `ConfirmUser`, etc. Then, on `WebApiService`, you would implement those methods, utilizing, of course, your Web Api. However, you MVC site should interact only with `IService`, and then you can use a dependency injection framework to inject `WebApiService` for `IService`. Then, if for some reason, you later needed to switch to using Entity Framework directly, for example, you can create something like:

```
public class EntityFrameworkService : IService
```

And, then inject that instead. Since the MVC application knows only about `IService`, you don't need to change anything there at all.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, my Web API services are separate projects and hosted independently. UI may interact with those services either as AJAX requests or in traditional MVC style depending on business functionality. As such, when the API sends mails, it can't include links pointing to the MVC app because I don't want API to have knowledge about MVC actions.
Thinking more of it, second approach seems to be ugly particularly account creation scenario. With that, UI needs to have 3 links: "Login"", "Register" & "Confirm Account"; the last link being strange. Any ideas?

Comment: First, the fact that it's hosted independently is irrelevant. If you don't want it to have knowledge of the MVC app, just have the link to include in the email be part of the API, so that the MVC app would pass that to the Web Api. Also, we're not talking about links here. You're thinking too literally. These are method calls the MVC application would make. In something like "Signup", both `RegisterUser` and `SendConfirmationEmail` would occur in the same action. I just broke it up here as it might be separate Web Api actions.

Comment: I think you are right. While making calls, UI can send it's links to Web API. This has an issue when load balancers come into picture but that is fine. Given other facts, that approach makes sense. Silly on my part; thanks.

Comment: Load balancers shouldn't effect anything, unless you're sending users to a naked IP. Even then, it probably wouldn't be an issue if the load balancing was set up properly. Otherwise, it's all hitting the same URL, regardless of what actual server is responding.